# Filter an Array of Object that has different attributes

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I want to filter so that it only shows objects with Id with atleast "something" that is not empty in it besides Id. so this array below

```
[{id:1, a:true, b:[]},
 {id:2, a:false, b:[]},
 {id:3, foo:'', bar:{}},
 {id:4, bla:[1,2,3], blabla:{x: 1}}];
```

show give me the following result:

```
[{id:1, a:true, b:[]},
 {id:4, bla:[1,2,3], blabla:{x: 1}}];
```

This is where I am at however I know this way of doing is is not ideal even if it gives me the above result :

```
const  dataArray = [
        {id:1, a:true, b:[]},
        {id:2, a:false, b:[]},
        {id:3, foo:'', bar:{}},
        {id:4, bla:[1,2,3], blabla:{x: 1}}
];

const filterArray = dataArray.filter((value) => {
        return value.foo != '' && value.a != false
})

console.log(filterArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cnuvkg54/

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to filter for. Only objects where id is set and at least one other property that is not undefined?

Comment: Please define "*"something" that is not empty*" more clearly. What is the expected output, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check objects with keys.

```js
const 
    array = [{ id: 1, a: true, b: [] }, { id: 2, a: false, b: [] }, { id: 3, foo: '', bar: {} }, { id: 4, bla: [1, 2, 3], blabla: { x: 1 } }],
    result = array.filter(({ id, ...o }) => Object.values(o).some(v => v && typeof v === 'object'
        ? Object.keys(v).length
        : v
    ));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for that that's what I was trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly this could be a way of dealing with non truthy properties, other than `id`

```js
const dataArray = [
  { id: 1, a: true, b: [] },
  { id: 2, a: false, b: [] },
  { id: 3, foo: "", bar: {} },
  { id: 4, bla: [1, 2, 3], blabla: { x: 1 } },
  { id: 5 }, // should not be in filterArray
  { id: 6, a: false } // should not be filterArray
];

// with Object.keys
const filterArray = dataArray.filter(({ id, ...data }) =>
  Object.keys(data).some((key) => data[key])
);

// with Object.entries
const filterArray2 = dataArray.filter(({ id, ...data }) =>
  Object.entries(data).some(([, prop]) => prop)
);

console.log(filterArray);
console.log(filterArray2);
```

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear before but you basically figured it out thanks for the response was helpful in getting me too the solution,